# Inserting XML words to MySQL using Java Pattern and Matcher

Tags: java, mysql, xml, regex

I want to keep track of word usage in a group chat using MySQL database. Currently messages passed into the insertWords method is an XML string. The XML string can have special characters such as `&apos;` and `&quot;`. Is there a better way than using String.replace to convert XML formatted strings to normal messages?

If my message is: `I&apos;m bad, but they aren&apos;t that &quot;good&quot;`

How can I convert it to: `I'm bad, but they aren't that "good"`

My code will insert apos 2 times and quot 2 times. How do I fix this?

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\w']+");

PreparedStatement insertWordStmt = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO word (word, count) VALUES (?, 1) " +
        "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count=count+1");

public void insertWords(String msg) {
    msg = msg.toLowerCase();
    try {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(msg);
        while ( m.find() ) {
            String word = msg.substring(m.start(), m.end());
            insertWordStmt.setString(1, word);
            insertWordStmt.executeUpdate();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What should be stored can you explain with example ?

Comment: NVM I found my answer. I downloaded org.apache.commons package and used StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(message);

Answer (score 0):

to add double quote matching, try

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\w'\"]+");
```

EDIT after comments

```
msg = msg.toLowerCase().replace("&apos;","'").replace("&quote;","\"");
```

Comment: Thanks. I just realized that the messages being passed into insertWords are XML formatted. I edited my first post. Please read it. I still need help.

Comment: NVM I found my answer. I downloaded org.apache.commons package and used StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(message);